# How do you reduce cpu/frames while having a mousehook, without causing mouselag? c++

Tags: c++, winapi, opengl

As easy as that, my mousehook causes mouselag when I use `Sleep();` and I dont know how to fix it.

Having a `Sleep();` in the messageloop of my mousehook causes systemwide mouselag, something I want to avoid.

So how do I reduce cpu/frames without lagging the mouse/system?

```
Mousehook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, HookCallback, NULL, 0);
```

to laglessly work with:

```
 LRESULT CALLBACK HookCallback(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
switch (wParam)
    {
    case WM_RBUTTONDOWN:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
return CallNextHookEx(Mousehook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Whenever I call `Sleep();` anywhere here, it causes the hook to freeze or lag the mouse. And I'm stumped as how to fix it.

Comment: Don't sleep in hooks?

Comment: You cannot `Sleep()` and not `Sleep()` at the same time. If you want mouse event propagation to not be delayed, don't add a delay.

Comment: Do you know what `Sleep` does? If so, how can you be surprised that `Sleep` has this effect?

Comment: My mousehook callback doesnt call a sleep, but my msg loop currently does, I was not aware this would cause mouselag no.

Comment: Don't sleep on the thread that runs the gui message pump, it delays pretty much everything. If delays are needed, start a timer and react on it when that fires the completion message back into the message pump.

Answer (score 1):

> How do you reduce cpu/frames, while having a mousehook, without causing mouselag?

Move the mouse hook to a different thread than the one that is driving your cpu/frame usage.  Then you can reduce the cpu/frames without affecting the mouse.